# How to select an element from a sub-documents array with two conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following Mongoose schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    attributes: [{
        key: { type: String, required: true },
        references: [{
            value: { type: String, required: true },
            reference: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }
        }]
    }
});
```

A document that follows this schema would look like this:

```
{
    attributes: [
        {
            key: 'age', references: [{ value: '35', reference: 298387adef... }]
        },
        {
            key: 'name', references: [{
                value: 'Joe', reference: 13564afde...,
                value: 'Joey', reference: 545675cdab...,
        }
        ...
    ]           
}
```

I'd like to select attributes according to the following conditions:
 - the key is `name` for example
 - the attribute with key `name` has a least one reference with a value `Joe`.

Ideally, I'd like to AND-chain many of these conditions. For example, `{'name': 'Joe'}` and `{'age': '35'}`.

I can't seem to find a way of doing that Mongoose. I've tried the following Mongoose queries without any good results (it gives either false positives or false negatives):

```
 // First query
 query.where('attributes.key', attribute.key);
 query.where('attributes.references.value', attribute.value);

 // Second
 query.and([{ 'attributes.key': attribute.key }, { 'attributes.$.references.value': attribute.value }]);

 // Third
 query.where('attributes', { 'key': attribute.key, 'references.value': { $in: [attribute.value] }});
```

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`elemMatch`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch) to find docs that contain an `attributes` element that matches multiple terms:

```js
query.elemMatch(attributes, { key: 'name', 'references.value': 'Joe' })
```

You can't chain multiple `elemMatch` calls together though, so if you want to AND multiples of these you'd need to explicitly build up a query object using `$and` and `$elemMatch` instead of chaining `Query` method calls.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had not understood how $elemMatch actually worked. You save my day :)